# Googleupdate.exe /c parameter is used for?

Tags: google-chrome

I recently installed google chrome v. 17, and among programs loaded when the system start I found the file below:

> C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe" /c

This file would serve to check updates for google chrome, **but `/c` parameter is used for?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that this is the same GoogleUpdate produced by the open-source Omaha release, the /c argument instructs it to start up the "long-lived" core Omaha process.

You can see all the available arguments at the top of [trunk/goopdate/goopdate.cc](http://code.google.com/p/omaha/source/browse/trunk/goopdate/goopdate.cc), and the core of that core process in [trunk/core/core.cc](http://code.google.com/p/omaha/source/browse/trunk/core/core.cc)

In that second file you'll see the description of core:

```
// Core is the long-lived Omaha process. It runs one instance for the
// machine and one instance for each user session, including console and TS
// sessions.
// If the same user is logged in multiple times, only one core process will
// be running.
```

Comment: Those links now redirect to these URLs

https://github.com/google/omaha/blob/master/omaha/goopdate/google_update.cc

https://github.com/google/omaha/blob/master/omaha/core/core.cc

Comment: This was really helpful too.
https://github.com/google/omaha/blob/master/omaha/common/command_line_unittest.cc